# javascript regex for whole and decimal numbers (money)

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal, currency

Trying to write a javascript regex for forcing users to enter decimal after a whole number, doesn't seem like many people want to do this as my searches have yielded nothing that suits my needs.

`Match: 2.00 20.00 200.00 1.73 0.10`

`No Match: .2 .20 . 1 10 1.0 0.1 1.`

Here is what I have currently:

`var regexp=/^[0-9]{1,}\.{1}[0-9]{2}$/;`

In plain english, users must enter money in X.XX format. Just a whole number by itself is disallowed.

I'd appreciate any help and also teaching insight anyone has to offer in making this work.

**EDIT:**

Here is code:

```
var notempty=/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\$]/g;
var money=/^[0-9]{1,}\.{1}[0-9]{2}$/;

if ( (notempty.test(document.getElementById('numbers').value)) && (!money.test(document.getElementById('numbers').value)) )
{alert('Wrong format');}
```

Comment: How about `/^\d+\.\d{2}$/`? - http://regexr.com/3cak4

Comment: @JoshCrozier Just note that would also allow `0003.01` which might not be what OP wants.

Comment: That's the same thing I already have, just written differently, and no, it doesn't work. "1" returns true, although "10" does not. "1" would need to be written as "1.00" in order to match.

Comment: @Bob with your regex "1" is returning false to me.

Comment: How does your approach not work? Give some examples, because all of the `No Match` items don't match and all of the `Match` items do match.

Comment: I'm running a double condition check on a form field the first checks to see if the field contains anything at all and the second is the above regex to check for monetary formatting.

Comment: Have you tried to test the regex alone? Use your browser's console.

Comment: Ok, so I just removed the 1st condition, `notempty` and just checked for the monetary formatting, and you guys are right, it does work. Any idea why it's not working with a double condition check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial regular expression is correct, the problem is actually your `notempty` check can short-circuit the condition if the value is `false`. For example if you have a character which is not a letter, number, dollar sign, or period the `/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\$]/` it will evaluate `false` and ignore the item after the `&&` as the values don't matter because `false && [any conditions] = false`. For example if the input value was `"+"`:

```
if ( false && ... )
    // invalid format [the expression was false, so this isn't ran]
```

Since the first condition is `false` the entire expression becomes false, leading to a improper `"correct format"`. The "empty check" isn't needed in this case anyway, you can simply have:

```
if (money.test(document.getElementById('numbers').value) {
    // valid format
} else {
    // invalid format
}
```

As noted by @JostCrozier, your expression can be simplified to: `/^\d+\.\d{2}$/`, which is functionally equivalent.